# How can I directly fetch the data from URL to Azure Blob

Tags: python, url, azure-blob-storage

I'm using the requests.get but it is downloading the file on the machine where I executed the file, Is there a way to skip this?

```
r = requests.get(url,stream=True)
    file_name = url.split("/")[-1]
    with open(file_name, 'wb') as data:
        for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size = 1024*1024):
            if chunk:
                data.write(chunk)
    block_blob_service.create_blob_from_path(path.join(container,blob),
                          data.name,
                          file_name ,
                          content_settings=ContentSettings(content_type=mimetypes.guess_type('./%s' %url.split("/")[-1])[0]))
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-python-how-to-use-blob-storage

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the code below.

```
r = requests.get(url,stream=True)
block_blob_service.create_blob_from_stream(container_name, blob_name, io.BytesIO(r.content))
```

Or

```
r = requests.get(url,stream=True)
block_blob_service.create_blob_from_bytes(container_name, blob_name, r.content)
```

Hope it helps.